# Leer multiples direcciones de un maestro desde un esclavo Arduino

Tags: arduino, programación-funcional

estoy atascadisimo con lo siguiente:
Hay una placa la cual posee un display de 7 segmentos de 3 digitos, deseo leer como envia los datos este display desde un arduino (como esclavo).
El tema es que con la funcion típica `Wire.begin(x);` Solo permite leer una direcion, y ya vi que este display almacena cada digito en una direccion diferente.

Me gustaria saber si existe alguna formula para poder captar cada uno de esos digitos.

pd: el display muestra temperatura desde un sensor.

pd2: no adjunto mas codigo porque no existe, realice multiples cambios desde el codigo de ejemplo de la libreria `Wire.h` pero ninguno funcional, sigo leyendo solo 1 adress.
pd3: stoy abierto a otros lenguajes de programacion, si es que es necesario cambiar para poder lograr recibir este dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien necesita ayuda con este asunto.
Se puede solucionar utilizando hilos. Mas especificamente, yo use la loiobreria protothreads en arduino, solo recuerden no utilizar "delay", utilicen "millis", es mas recomendable.